# How can one calculate the average of last X values in a row, but ignoring a set number of cells

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I've been trying hard to solve this but haven't managed yet.

I have this sheet I'm using to keep track of my expenses on a monthly basis and every month I create a new column to register different types of expenses from that month. On each line, I have different expenses like groceries, entertainment, car, etc, and every month I add new values. The heather for each column has the month it corresponds to.

At the end of each line, after the last inserted monthly data, I also have some columns which I use to make calculations, such as total average and total value, so that I know how much I spend on each category. What I would like to do is to have another cell, at the end of each line, calculating the last 6 months average for each category (meaning, for each line)

[image: example of the sheet]

As you can see in the image, every thin to the right of column AO is statistics. In column AR I would like to have a formula to calculate the last 6 month average, meaning it would look to the 6 months to the left of column AP (any cell with values) and do the average of those.

I would like this do be done without hardcoding "AP" column, since that changes every time I create the column for a new month. There is no problem though in hardcoding the number of statistics columns that are found at the end of each line (which are 5 in this example).

Any help is deeply appreciated

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168294/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to use `byrow()` in cell `AR3`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  byrow( 
    A3:AO, 
    lambda( 
      row, 
      if( 
        not(len(join("", row))), 
        iferror(1/0), 
        lambda( 
          lastSixMonths, 
          average(lastSixMonths) 
        )( 
          query( 
            transpose( { row; column(row) } ), 
            "select Col1 
             where Col1 is not null 
             order by Col2 desc 
             limit 6", 0 
          ) 
        ) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```